# Linux virtual machine, memory overflow caused by endless loop

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, virtualbox

I am using a virtual machine of linux 64-bit for programming in assembly. 
The virtual machine I use is a copy of the version that is on the computers at my university. This means I do not have the permission to open all folders with a normal 
'student' account. For instance I can't open the root folder and the lost+found folder. I don't if  this is necessary to solve my problem.

One of my test programs turned in an endless loop that made an infinite long string. This caused that the virtual hard drive of my virtual machine is now completely full and no free space is available. I'm normally using windows so unfortunately I am not that familiar with linux.

I tried searching through my folders and came across a 140.7TB large file called proc kore. After searching a bit I found out that I shouldn't be worried about this file as it is some kind of virtual file that represents the maximum amount of RAM your version of linux supports.

However, it is not clear for me where to look if I want to clear the place in my virtual drive where my Strings are saved. Is there any short way to clear the location where a lot strings are stored by default?

In forward thanks

Comment: You should post that on superuser, not stack overflow. Quick pointer though: you should use unix tool `du` to find which folder of your home directory uses more space. Something like `du -hxd1 ~` should get you started, then you replace ~ by other directory to narrow down the files

Comment: also, `/proc` is not a directory of your hard drive. It is a fake directory, created by linux, to give you information about your computer. If you open `/proc/cpuinfo`, you will get information about your CPU, for instance.

Comment: You can either use a new virtual machine image, or mount the disk image to a small generic vm where you have root, and use that to clean up or extract your work (assuming you didn't use filesystem encryption).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've found an answer. With help of the du command I found out that something was terribly wrong in the map where my program was, though I couldn't find a bare thing, until I turned the option 'show hidden files' on. Then a 26gb large file called xsession-errors.old showed up. It stopped growing because there was no room left for the file to grow and used all the free space.

26gb of session errors located in a hidden file. Well that certainly pissed me off. I hope this explanation will help someone in the future who's got a similar problem.

Thanks to qdii for posting a comment and helping me out